# overflow:auto -- scrollbar not scrolling in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Why is scrollbar [here](http://mayacove.com/dev/test.html) refusing to move in IE6 (and *only* IE6)?

Comment: why is url I posted not showing in my orig post???? it's http://mayacove.com/dev/test.html

Comment: Hey, calm down. I am sure you will sort this out. Also: IE6. You serious? What does this abbreviation mean? Where does it come from? The [Jurassic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic)?

Comment: what do you mean??  yes IE6..  just following orders...;-)  this is for work...;-)  I've done this sort of thing many times, it's never happened to me before that a srollbar won't scroll in IE6...  thank you...

Comment: Is there anyone in the world still caring about IE6?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work when I remove

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled='true', sizingMethod='scale', src='images/search_popup_bg_middle-2.png')
```

from

```
TABLE.searchPopupContainerTable TD.centerCell2
```

in **ie6.css**

Comment: ok, here's the weird thing: how come it's not happening here?   http://mayacove.com/dev/test2.html 
it's from this "template" that I did other one..

Comment: (b/c I can't remove code you mention.. if I do drop shadows on left & right in that div disappear...)  thank you..

Comment: I guess the lesson here is that if you want to support IE6, you'd best forget about going overboard with drop shadows and other fancy features. IE6 simply has too many issues, bugs and missing features for you to successfully do both. It's hard enough with IE7, but virtually impossible with IE6. Explain to your boss that supporting IE6 will double the development costs and reduce the things you can do. Check the usage figures for IE6 - it's below 2% now and falling every month. Is it really worth all the extra hassle just to support those few hold-outs?

Comment: Agreed. The shadow effect shouldn't be a deal breaker. I would just use a more generic design for older browsers. It should be accepted at this point that everything does not need to look the same in every browser.

Comment: If you need to support Chinese users then dealing with IE6 is a must.